# My sql sales query to sort the sales data

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is my sales report like bellow

```
 sno    order_id    code    value 
1              1    Tax         100
2              1    Total       200
3              1    Pay         300
4              2    Tax         120
5              2    Total       230
```

But i want report like bellow

```
sno  order_id     tax    total     pay
1       1         100    200      300
2       2         120   230      0
```

can any one help me to write a mysql query to do this

Comment: You mean to help you create new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select @s := @s + 1 as sno,
       order_id,
       max(case when code = 'tax' then value end) as tax,
       max(case when code = 'total' then value end) as total,
       max(case when code = 'pay' then value end) as pay
from your_table
cross join (select @s := 0) num
group by order_id
```